# best of 12 out of 14 in python

Tags: python

I have a list of 14 numbers in a list

list=[0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.5, 1.0, 2.0]

I have to sum the best of 12 among the list

New to code have no idea.

Comment: Maybe sort them and the slice off 12?

Comment: Really, if you let someone here show you how to do this, you are missing all the fun of teaching yourself, the unconfined joy available as you try to figure out just how to bend the will of the mighty computer to your indomitable spirit.  Don't stand on the side of the pool shivering in your bathing suit, dive in, join the fun.

Comment: What is "the best of 12"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l=[0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.5, 1.0, 2.0]
l.sort()
l=l[0:12]
print(l)
total=0
for element in range(0,len(l)):
    total=total+l[element]
print(total)
```

Hope this help! but try to learn this language by yourself, you will surely be enjoying python:)